# How can AS3 front-end code and AS2 server-side scripting send objects back and forth, while keeping their methods?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2, server-side, flash

Given the following AS3 front-end code:

```
m_nc.connect("rtmp://" + pPrimaryIP + "/appname/"+ pVID, pUID, pConfig);
```

and the following AS2 server-side scripting code:

```
application.onConnect = function(pClientObj, pUID, pConfig)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

where pConfig is an object of type Configuration, as defined in the AS3 code, having the method:

```
public function copy(pConfig:Configuration):void
```

apparently when you try to send the object across while connecting, it loses that method and any other methods.  Yet its fields remain basically intact, at least if they're primitives.  I can see why this might be so, but is there not some way to keep this loss from happening?  I really want to be able to not just send it to the AS2 without losing anything, but to also be able to send it back to the AS3 without losing anything.  Is this possible?  If so how?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should look at LocalConnection, a class available to both AS2 as AS3 (AS1 even)
[clicky](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html)